How do I integrate ezdxf into my .NET app?
How does one integrate ezdxf into a .Net app? According to this site:
https://groups.google.com/g/python-ezdxf/c/Z_bfWOS2dXI
It mentions to look at the site:
https://netdxf.codeplex.com/ which doesn't exist.
My program is written in C# and .Net. Do I need to install python to use this ezdxf? I have no experience in Python. Or like mentioned in the first article, is there a .dll I can reference?
Tony
I'm just researching for now on how to edit a dxf to add dimension styles.

See https://github.com/haplokuon/netDxf for netdxf. Yes, ezdxf is a Python library.

You can create a file, using C#.
These file content must be the following:
import ezdxf
doc = ezdxf.new()
msp = doc.modelspace()
msp.add_line((0, 0), (1, 0), dxfattribs={"layer": "myLayer"})
doc.saveas("C:\\dev\\myfile.dxf")

Then, execute that file, using something like the Run Python Script from C#.
